# How do I import a CSV file into DolphinDB?

Tags: database, csv, import, dolphindb

I have a CSV file and I want to import my data into a DolphinDB table so that I can conduct some queries on it.
Given the top 10 lines of my data:

```
ID  TICKER  date        VOL     PRC     BID     ASK
1   AMZN    1997.05.15  6029815 23.5    23.5    23.625
2   AMZN    1997.05.16  1232226 20.75   20.5    21
3   AMZN    1997.05.19  512070  20.5    20.5    20.625
4   AMZN    1997.05.20  456357  19.625  19.625  19.75
5   AMZN    1997.05.21  1577414 17.125  17.125  17.25
6   AMZN    1997.05.22  983855  16.75   16.625  16.75
7   AMZN    1997.05.23  1330026 18  18  18.125
8   AMZN    1997.05.27  726192  19  19  19.125
9   AMZN    1997.05.28  382132  18.375  18.375  18.625
```

Is there any tutorials for data importing?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this tutorial to import csv files to DolphinDB. https://github.com/dolphindb/Tutorials_EN/blob/master/import_data.md